# How to load a gif (with transparency) on a plane in Aframe (glitch)?

Tags: html, gif, aframe, webvr

Hey guys I'm new to Aframe and trying to set up a whole bunch of gifs in a spatial web environment.

I'm getting a bit stuck in loading a gif on a plane.

I've loaded the image through the assets folder of Aframe (glitch),
currently it looks like this:

```
   <a-assets>

    <img id="dance" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/89b3ce36-3eac-4bb0-865c-585a7fe58409%2Fdance.gif?1556817051483.gif"  >

  </a-assets>

  <a-plane src="#dance" position="5 3 -5" transparent="true" ></a-plane>
```

Right now the gif shows up, but it is static. How could I get it to start playing?

Answer (score 2):

A-Frame does not support GIFs by default. You need to use a third-party component to render GIFs: https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader

Comment: I tried with gifs with a transparent background, and somehow the frames all overlap instead of show one by one. (non-transparent gif load normally, as you can see here: https://franks.glitch.me/ ) Any ideas on how to fix that? :)

Comment: Hi @Marijn, I did some test and have found that aframe-gif-shader works OK with aframe v 0.9.0 ... Unfortunately with 1.0.x it doesn't. If you found the solution, it would be great you share :) Regards

Answer (score 0):

Third-party component aframe-gif-shader can help to render GIFs but only support aframe below version 1.2.

I have made modifications to support aframe version 1.3.0 and above in the [aframe-gif-shader](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader). You can find the updated code at https://github.com/gloomcheng/aframe-gif-shader.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).