# How do I place animated GIF in a-frame?

Tags: components, aframe, animated-gif

Using [a-frame](https://aframe.io/), how do I place an animated gif on my scene?

Following the answer on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55960135/how-to-load-a-gif-with-transparency-on-a-plane-in-aframe-glitch), I added these third-party components: [aframe-gif-component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-component);
[aframe-gif-shader](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader).

I read the documentation and followed the installation guides. However, it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong, here?

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader/master/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-component/master/dist/aframe-gif-component.min.js"></script>


<a-scene>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive:circle;" position="-1.5 1.5 0" material="shader:gif;src:url(https://i.imgur.com/L6HkVPx.gif);" gif=""></a-entity>
  <a-sky color="pink"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Without a link to runnable code people can look at and suggest solutions is hard to help. Glitch is a good option https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: @Diego Marcos, You can run the code snippet I provided, on my post, on this same page.

Comment: It doesn't run on StackOverflow. Click on run and see the errors. Best is to provide a standalone version for easy inspection and debugging like  glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: This particular script doesn't run on StackOverflow as it is intended to because something is wrong with it (and that is what I am trying to find out). Other scripts usually run. Besides, being just 7 lines long, I thought it would be easier having everything here, instead of directing people to a different page. I will set up a glitch account though, and will update the post, soon.

Answer (score 0):

your issue seems to be, that the external mayognaise uses aframe 0.9.0 https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader and you are using 1.0.4

Comment: Did you try and it worked? Even with 0.9.0, mine still does not.